# How can I use the value of a variable in Python format string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Please tell me something like this is possible in Python.  I can't seem to get it to work

```
MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT = 24
myFormatStr = '{mykey:<${MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT}s}'
myStr = myFormatStr.format(mykey='Something')
```

I keep getting

```
KeyError: 'MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT'
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `mcl = MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT` to the parameters fed to `format`:

```
MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT = 24
myFormatStr = '{mykey:<{mlc}s}'
myStr = myFormatStr.format(mykey='Something',
                           mlc = MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT)
print(myStr)
# Something
```

You can also refer to local variables in your format string, and inform `format` of the values by passing it `**locals()`:

```
MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT = 24
myFormatStr = '{mykey:<{MY_LENGTH_CONSTRAINT}s}'
myStr = myFormatStr.format(mykey='Something', **locals())
print(myStr)
# Something
```

(or similarly, use global variables, and pass `format` `**globals()`.)

Comment: Of course, but I was wondering if this could be done implicitly.  I believe ruby has a feature like the one I'm looking for here in Python.